# Is there a way to set an alias to columns using Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Suppose I have a model for a table in which the columns are written in Portuguese. In this way:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'nota_id', 'identificacao'
    ];

    //more..
}
```

Currently, to set and get values I do as follows:

```
$order = new Order();
$order->nota_id = 1;
$order->identificacao = '123456';

echo $order->nota_id;
echo $order->identificacao;
```

Rename columns directly in the table is not an option. But I need to do something like this:

```
$order = new Order();
$order->invoiceId = 1;
$order->identification = '123456';

echo $order->invoiceId;
echo $order->identification;
```

And at the end, when I save to the database using eloquent, "invoiceId" and "identification" will be converted to "nota_id" and "identificacao".

Are there any packages that solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with laravel mutators.

Inside your model you can create mutator/accessor functions (for retrieving & setting values based on your needs) like:

```
getInvoiceIdAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['nota_id'];
}

getIdentificationAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['identificacao'];
}
```

Pay attention to the naming i used it's not a random name for your function. The structure must be:

`get` + the name you want + `Attribute`

Read more about laravel mutators [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators)

Then to access them you simple do what you did in your expected behaviour:

```
echo $order->invoiceId;
echo $order->identification;
```

Comment: Mutator or Accessor?? you should also write the mutator function in answer..

Comment: Pretty much same logic, one is for retrieving the other one is for setting a value that's why i pasted also the documentation for a deeper look but also focused on the question based on what needs to be achieved.